# Battery drain despite system shutdown

Tags: hardware, shutdown, battery

I have a dual boot setup with Linux Mint 20.3 and Windows 10 on my HP laptop.

For the past few days, I noticed that when I shut the laptop down, *my battery still drains.* I'm talking like -50% in 8 hours of system being turned off.

- I've tried using TLP package to enable `USB_AUTOSUSPEND` and `DISABLE_ON_SHUTDOWN` for bluetooth, WiFi and WWAN but that didn't work.
- I've also tried restoring to an old snapshot prior to noticing the issue.

What did work temporarily was removing the built-in battery & CMOS battery and putting it back. It didn't drain the night I did the battery fix (Just booted to make sure the system was fine and shutdown) but started again the next day after normal use.

Also when I did restore to an old snapshot, it didn't drain also on the first boot also but followed suit the next boot.

I find it odd cause I have being daily driving linux for half a year now so why now all of a sudden this happens? Any idea on what might be the problem?

Here is the output of

- [`lshw`](https://pastebin.com/raw/wUfXpnFC)
- [`lspci`](https://pastebin.com/raw/47d3JPzU)

**Edit:** So it's seems like updating the my BIOS worked? I can't be sure this is the main reason as I did try other fixes such as booting into my Windows and disabling WOL for WiFi and shutting down Windows properly using

```
poweroff /s /f /t 0
```

Then right after all that, I updated my BIOS and haven't drained for the past two days. I'll keep on monitoring to see if I can find the root cause.

Comment: Possibly unrelated to anything else but personal experience : Has your laptop gone through any sort of X-Ray scan recently ?

Comment: Is it possible that instead of shutting it down you instead put it to sleep? That could explain everything.

Comment: Not that I know of @MC68020

Comment: I used "sudo shutdown -H 0" to shutdown so I highly doubt that. @ArtemS.Tashkinov

Comment: This sounds like something which needs to be RMA'ed. This shouldn't be happening no matter which OS you're using to shut it down.